# Access to xml String resources in HTML file from Assets

Tags: android, html, xml

I would like to know if there is any way to get the value of one string located in /res/values/strings.xml from html located in assets.

My value in strings.xml:

```
<string name="test">Hello world</string>
```

My html in assets:

`<p>@string/test</p>`

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Think you need some javascript and a javascript interface.

Comment: @greenapps I'm coming to that conclusion, do that with the javascript DOM. Ty for your comment.